# Dynamic creation of queues in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel queues for processing the data one by one, this is my code for single queue

```
public function webhooks(Request $request)
{
 {
        $data = 'i am passing some data';
        Log::info("Request Cycle with Queues Begins");
        $job = (new webhookQueue($data));
        $this->dispatch($job);
        Log::info("Request Cycle with Queues Ends");
 }
}
```

if i will be getting more data at around 1000 responses, to handle this in single queue it will take more time. For this i want to use dynamically creation of queues, so is there any way for creating dynamic queues. I have found supervisor for this where we can set maximum queues, but not dynamic.
Some one please help me. Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add number of processes in superviosr numprocs=8, and create the job in smart way based on data. I would suggest split your data to chunks each chunk with 500, then dispatch the job two times.

```
//job 1
$job1 = (new webhookQueue($data1));
$this->dispatch($job1);

//job2
$job1 = (new webhookQueue($data2));
$this->dispatch($job12);
```

Hope this will work for you. You can also see some discussion in laracast https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/running-multiple-queue-workers

Comment: Thank you for replying, as you said we can set 8 process using supervisor, can we set dynamic process per response, and delete that process after completion.

Answer (score 0):

The queue doesn't do the processing, it just lines up the data so it can be processed at a later date. So there's no need to run multiple queues like you're trying.

What you should do is have a single queue which contains all the message payloads and use multiple queue workers to process the data. This can be done with Supervisord as per the docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#supervisor-configuration

i.e.

```
numprocs=8
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, as you said we can set 8 process using supervisor, can we set dynamic process per response, and delete that process after completion

Comment: That's not something which is supported by Supervisor. However, if there aren't any jobs on the queue then the queue worker instances will be using very little system resource.

Comment: As many as you want - it's really a case of how powerful your server is and how long your tasks take to process. Start with a low number (why not 8?) and watch to see if the job backlog on the queue is piling up. If it is, you need more workers.

Comment: ok, thank you i got clear idea, these workers will work in parallel or sync?

Comment: I believe supervisor processes run in parallel.